# display individual listView for every item in a listView

Tags: listview

I have a form with 2 listViews. When I select an item (parent) in the left listView I want to display a list of items (children) in the right listView.

[This picture](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3754/7ugoam9k_png.htm) might clarify what I mean.

Is there a simple coding approach to achieve that?

I'd be very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: you are loading list from database??

Comment: No, I add everything via textBox input. Both listViews have their own textBox linked to it. There is no save/load feature yet.

Comment: As per my knowledge and according to your need there should be something from where u can fetch image after filtering. it may be local database or web services

Comment: So far I had no luck finding a pre-built database. What I want to do is to link a list of items to their respective category, like "Dog" and "Cat" to the category "Pets". Do I need to write/load dynamically from/to files to accomplish that? (I added a link to a picture to my question to show what I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. I simply copy the items of ListView 1 in a dictionary, representing the keys, whereas the subitems (categorical entries) or values are represented in the form of generic lists whose individual contents are displayed in ListView 2, which is easily done thanks to the ListView ItemSelectionChanged event.